# Recipient address wildcard support in AWS SES

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

The question is similar [to this one](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=217746);

> When receiving email via SES, it would be helpful to have some basic
>   wildcard support when generating receipt rules.
>
> We have a use case that relies upon dynamic labels such as:
>   user+{nonce}-{app}@domain.com
>
> The {app} component of the address is used to route to different
>   applications for processing.

That one from the AWS forum remains unanswered after 3 years, so asking here in case something has changed or there is a workaround.

Basically, what I need is creating many (thousands probably) addresses like `{someEntityId}@example.com` so users can send content to those addresses (SES has some pretty low limits here so it isn't an option)

or

Having `receiving-stuff-{someEntityIdWildcardHere}@example.com` so if I get an email to receiving-stuff-auHKs5On5@example.com I know what to do.

**Extra info**: another option is getting `someEntityId` from the email sender (this is already done), but it has other issues, like having to create an email per each entity. Im also using WorkMail so I can't setup a domain level receipt rule because WorkMail would stop working (I've seen this happening).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you just receive to `*@example.com` and have your application (or a little Lambda function or something in front of it, if you need to dole things out to *multiple* apps) parse the address and distribute internally from there?

Comment: @ceejayoz that would brake AWS WorkMail integration with the domain example.com, I'll add that to the question, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SES Rules** support the usual *plus-notation*, for example *user+**something**@example.com*.

So what you can do is:

1. Create a *SES Rule* for your `receiving-stuff@example.com` address. That will catch all emails for `receiving-stuff+{something}@example.com`.

   - The first *Action* can be your **Lambda**, or store emails to *S3*.
   - The second *Action* is **Stop Rule Set** - that's important to stop forwarding emails for `receiving-stuff@` to *WorkMail*.
2. The next *SES Rule* is the original WorkMail rule for the whole domain.

With these in place any email for `receiving-stuff+{something}@` will be intercepted by the Lambda and *all other emails* will go straight to WorkMail.

In the end your configuration should be similar to this (I used `lambda@...` instead of `receiving-stuff@...`):

[image: SES Rule set]

I can also verify that my `ses-inbound-lambda` is being called:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event['Records'][0]['ses']['receipt']['recipients'][0])
```

Prints out: **lambda+some-extra-text@{example}.com**

And can also verify that *WorkMail* still works for other users:

[image: Amazon WorkMail]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: worked flawlessly